# VPS Accessible only through Serial Console

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vps

I have a VPS (with AphaVPS) that is running Ubuntu 18.04.

Since a couple of days, I cannot reach anymore the VPS through SSH.
I managed to connect using the browser serial console provided by AlphaVPS and from inside the VPS I cannot ping anything.

I spoke with the customer support of the provider and they say that everything is completely fine on their side.

What could be the issue then?

Before this happened I didn't make any configuration changes, nor installed any new package nor anything.

Comment: From the serial console, Did you check the ip of your server using `ip a or ifconfig -a` ? Or perhaps `nmcli device show` I don't remember for Ubuntu 18.04 if there is already NetworkManager.

Comment: Yes, I checked. The ip is still the same as before